# Using a regular string as a code for compiling

Tags: string

I need to make a function that receives a string such as:

```
int *ptr[20], *p, p2, p3[3];
```

and the function need to print:

ptr requires 80 bytes.
p requires 4 bytes.
p2 requires 4 bytes.
p3 requires 12 bytes.

to simplify to task, I would like to use the "fake" code in the string as a "real" code, and then just print the function sizeof(variable) to answer the question. I think it is the most simple way.
But how to do it?

Comment: please elaborate what did you mean by fake code and real code?

Comment: and the real code is? by the way you need to show some sample code too.

Comment: the fake code is the code inside the string. the string "short *s[2]" is a fake code because it is not inside the visual studio or the environment itself, but inside the string. I need to make the code "real" so it is inside the envoronment or use any steps to make it "real". So if I use the function sizeof(s) it would return the size of an array really declared and the same as what was in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is the ability to "evaluate" dynamically generated code.

Some languages -- usually they are evaluated (non-compiled) ones -- have such features, but C++ does not.

Even if it did, it wouldn't be a good solution here. You need a parser. For a formal approach, you may research lexers and context-free parsers. For an ad hoc approach...well...do whatever string manipulation you would like.